# Display text once within for loop on the first loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I have SQL query inside a for loop and I want to echo something of success of these query only once.  Here is part of my code

```html
<?php
   for($i=0;$i<sizeof($assigned_project_id);$i++){

 $sql2="SELECT * FROM assign_task INNER JOIN branch ON assign_task.branch_ID=branch.branch_ID WHERE project_ID=".$assigned_project_id[$i]." AND USER_ID=1";
              
                $query2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($query2)>0){
                echo" You have Assigned following Reports";
            }
                while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){

                    echo $row2['branch_ID']."&nbsp;".$row2['branch_name']."<br/>";
                }

            }
            ?>
```

I want to display the "You have Assigned following Reports" only once. Please help me.

Comment: so meve the message outside the loop. and running the querry in a loop is just a bad idea, get all the data you want and loop that

Comment: can you please give a example

Comment: if I place that outside the loop won't it echo if there is not single thing to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it as below

```
<?php
       $test =0 ;
       for($i=0;$i<sizeof($assigned_project_id);$i++){

            $sql2="SELECT * FROM assign_task INNER JOIN branch ON assign_task.branch_ID=branch.branch_ID WHERE project_ID=".$assigned_project_id[$i]." AND USER_ID=1";

            $query2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query2)>0){
               if($test==0){
                   echo" You have Assigned following Reports";
                  $test++;
               }
            }
            while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){

                echo $row2['branch_ID']."&nbsp;".$row2['branch_name']."<br/>";
            }

        }
        ?>
```